# What can be the possible disadvantages & advantages of a Javascript Framework like Ember or Angular over using simple Javascript for projects?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, angularjs, ember.js

I am thinking to use Javascript Framework for my project. But I am confused, should I use a Framework or use simple Javascript. Moreover, one more point I want to make I am not much experienced in Javascript. What would be your suggestions for one who is still at beginner level in Javascript?

Comment: Find someone who knows about javascript and various libraries and frameworks to analise your project, then determine the costs and benefits of using them. If you can't justify the expense, then likely it doesn't matter. Just use javascript, hopefully you'll know enough at the end of the project to know next time if a framework or library would help.

Comment: Great question but for starters, you should start with something that's easy to learn such as Backbone or Angular. I have nothing against Ember but that framework is not for beginners. The main advantage of frameworks over vanilla JS is that all the ceremonial stuff such as AJAX and other UI type functionalities are taken cared of so you can focus on your app's logic. It's not an end all, be all solution but it will help you become a more productive developer. Granted that you should know how things work behind the scenes as well.

Answer (score 5):

### Regarding beginner doubts:

I was at beginner level JavaScript when I started working with AngularJS last year. To learn the basics of it is really easy. What's even better is that it helps you do fairly complicated things with **very few lines of code**. Most of the code you write will be what AngularJS calls **directives**, which also turn out to be the most reusable pieces.

Some of the advanced concepts can be difficult to understand and will take some time though, but overall, I would say that **progressing through AngularJS has given me a better understanding of JavaScript**.

This was my experience at least, and **this post does not aim to sell AngularJS**. In my opinion, learning a programming language is, most of the time at least, better done by digging into the raw features of it on your own. But with JavaScript -- and all its quirks -- I found it very helpful to **have something to guide me** -- in this case, AngularJS.

### Regarding frameworks for projects:

When you want to have a large application, with a lot of code and interactions, I've found that frameworks help you a lot. There's a boom of JavaScript frameworks right now, all of which are pretty good. If you want to extend HTML and do declarative programming, there's **AngularJS**. If you want to work at different levels of abstraction, there's **Ember.js**. If you want to write most of the implementation yourself, then use **Backbone.js**. If you're doing a lot of GUI stuff, **ExtJS**. Most of these frameworks will help you write cleaner, modular and more testable code which greatly improves maintainability in the long run.

The downsides could possibly be:

1. learning curve - but if you are at beginner level, then you shouldn't worry about this.
2. overkill - for some projects you really don't need to include 500KB of frameworks and libraries
3. **mismatch** - and this, I think, might be the most important factor. For example some frameworks are more suited visual stuff, like charts and animations, while others are good for something else.

### Conclusion:

- determine what you want to achieve,
- find the right tool for the job,
- the framework/library (or neither if not required) will be of great help then

and, lastly, more like a general rule:

- **don't be afraid of doing things right just because it seems too unknown to you**

Answer (score 2):

Libraries can be very good. They can help you segment your code, they can help you do a lot of things more easily. I have begun to find backbone particularly helpful for AJAXy web aps. With JQuery, `$('#element').hide();` is far easier than `document.getElementById('element').style.display = "none";`, and JQuery `.toggle();` is even better than that. In most cases, they deal with cross browser issues for you very easily as well.

From a design/architecture standpoint, the big disadvantage is the overhead. Once you start using libraries and plug-ins for said libraries, who knows how the code quality is.

From a personal development standpoint, the biggest risk is that you will begin to use libraries as a crutch, and never bother to learn *why* or *how* these libraries do what they do. I hate when I see a web page with 15,000 (exageration) `<script>` blocks in the header, and they leverage perhaps 1/10th of the power of all the plugins and frameworks that they are using. It would be far better to write 5-10 lines of code, than to have an extra HTTP request, and load an entire JS module just to use one function that it contains.

My personal recommendation is to use libraries, but always endeavor to understand what they are doing, and to challenge yourself to write at least part of the JavaScript yourself, until you're at a point where you know what's going on inside JS, and why it's going on. Once you get to that point, you will be much better able to evaluate if a library or plug-in is really what you need, or if you should just write something yourself.

Comment: +1 Libraries can also lead to poor design decisions constrained by the developers knowledge of the library, such as using complex selectors and long chains of tail calls. Libraries are also commonly over used because the developer thinks they've loaded a library so it should be used for everything, even where native script or straight DOM is very much more efficient, less code to write and more robust.

Comment: Remember: easier but slower >> https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/564443848613847040